# How to compute all primes between upto $n$ in time $O(n)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, enumeration, primes

Suppose that I want to compute all the prime numbers between 2 and $n$. The natural way or most obvious way to do so is given below. Let $A$ is an array contain the numbers from $1$ to $n$.

1. For $j=2$ to $j=\sqrt n$
2. mark multiples of $j$ from $A$

Running time of this algorithm is $O(n \log n).$ It is easy to see that after first iteration there will be $n/2$ many unmarked elements and so on.

**The problem with this method is that some of the elements may be marked more than one time.**

**Question :** How to compute all the primes upto $n$ in $O(n)$ time?

Comment: If you only go over primes (which you can do at no cost), you improve the running time to $O(n\log\log n)$.

Comment: Does it help if you put all elements in a (doubly)linked-list and then do the marking-trick, but instead of marking an element; you simply remove it from the list (removing can be done in $O(1)$)? This solves the "marking things twice" issue. [I am not saying that in practice; this is a good idea]

Comment: Why would you try to mark multiples of 4?

Comment: Your algorithm is a degenerated version of Eratosthenes sieve, where for each j, if j has not been marked before, you mark all its multiple. The running time is thus rougly \sum_{p prime <= n} n/p which is O(n log (log n)) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes): not enough but not that bad already.

Comment: @gnasher729 I now notice that did not read the algorithm in the question correctly - I meant to say that you only use the elements that remain in the linked-list for the marking (smallest to largest) (since 4 is removed after doing the marking with 2; it will not be considered)

Comment: You never mentioned a linked list. And it would seem to be _extremly_ inefficient.

Comment: Do you want a solution that is O (n) or one that is fast? O (n log log n) is asymptotically slower than O (n), but log log n ≤ 6 for n ≤ 16 billion billions. So if you are looking for a solution with a time limit "within your life time", sieve + working hard to reduce constant factors might be the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) to enumerate all prime numbers up to $n$.  There are multiple algorithms; see the Wikipedia article I link for some examples.  The sieve of Atkin and wheel sieves apparently run in $O(n)$ time.